# Starting point of random walk does not affect conditional probability

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $S_n = \sum^n_0 X_k$ be random walk (with steps not necessarily of probability $\frac 12$). I want to show that $$ P(\text{hitting $2$ |  hitting $1$ $\cap$ $S_0=0$}) = P(\text{hitting $2$ |  hitting $1$})$$
where "hitting $x$" is the event $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{S_n=x\}$.

I conceptually can conceive that the starting point does not affect this probability so it can be deleted in the probability but I struggle to show it properly and rigorously, which makes me wonder if the equality is false.

I write this as $$P(\text{hitting $2$ |  hitting $1$ $\cap$ $S_0=0$})=\frac{P(\text{hitting $2$ $\cap$  hitting $1$ $\cap$ $S_0=0$})}{P(\text{hitting $1$ $\cap$ $S_0=0$})}$$

I can deal with the denominator $$P(\text{hitting $1$ $\cap$ $S_0=0$})=P\bigg(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{S_n=1\} \cap S_0=0\bigg)$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=1 \cap S_0=0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\sum^n_{k=0} X_k=1 \cap X_0=0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\sum^n_{k=1} X_k=1 \cap X_0=0)$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\sum^n_{k=1} X_k=1)P( X_0=0)=P( X_0=0)\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} X_k=1)$$

there will be a problem for $n=0$ but the last quantity is equal to $P(S_0=0)P(\text{hitting} 1)$, which is good news but I don't know if what I did is legal and I don't feel that the numerator can be dealt with similarly.

Comment: Are you familiar with the (strong) Markov property?

Comment: As stated, $S_0 = 0$, so what does putting $S_0 = 0$ in the conditioning do for you? Do you mean to let the starting point vary, so that $S_0 = x + \sum_{j = k}^{n}X_k$ under $P_x$?